# Error excute react native

Tags: javascript, android, sdk, react-native

I am new in react native. I want to run my friend project, but got some error in cmd

```
> react-native run-android
JS server already running.
Running D:\android\sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 05d6a6ba22d82a6a reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
adb server version (32) doesn't match this client (36); killing...
error: protocol fault (couldn't read status): Connection reset by peer
```

but got some error in cmd

```
:react-native-fabric:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72301Library FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-fabric:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72301Library'.
> Could not expand ZIP 'D:\android\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\recyclerview-v7\23.0.1\recyclerview-v7-23.0.1.aar'.
```

What is the problem?

Comment: You have to update your adb version, react-native couldn't run the emulator

Comment: I am tired to installing new adb version using device manager. Do you know the best way to install it?